# Return a parent tag attribute from selected child

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

```
<TAGS>    
  <PARENT ID="Parent Id">
     <MID>
      <CHILD ATTR="Child Value"
```

I have a piece of code which is selecting all the attribute values for some xml that correspond to "Child Value".

I also need to have the "Parent Value", to relate the two items, for future use.

My code currently locates and retrieves the child values, but I'm having difficulty getting the value from the Parent ID. What would be the correct syntax for this?

Currently the code is similar to this:

```
taglist = []
for parent in soup.find_all('tags'):
    for each in parent.find_all('child'):
        taglist.append(repr(each['attr']))
```

I want to retrieve, in this example the PARENT ID value, as the child is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the relevant [`find_parent()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
child.find_parent("parent", id=True)["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

because of the tags I'm assuming you are using python and beautifulsoup. If so, which versions?

There is a `.parent` that can be used like in:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parents

```py
child=soup.find("child", {"attr" : "value"})
for parent in child.parents:
    if parent.get('id')) == "Parent Id":
        print(parent)
```